# Pool architecture with friend

Tags: c++, architecture, pool

I'm working on a Pool architecture with templates:

Pool.h

```
template<class T>
class Pool<T>
{
public:
    static T* Create()
    {
        ...
        return new T();
    }
...
}
```

TComponent.h

```
template<class T>
class TComponent
{
public:
    static T* Create()
    {
        return s_pool.Create();
    }
    ...
protected:
    TComponent();
    ~TComponent();
private:
    static Pool<T> s_pool;
}
```

ExampleComponent.h

```
class ExampleComponent : public TComponent<ExampleComponent>
{
    friend class Pool<ExampleComponent>;
    ...
protected:
    ExampleComponent();
    ~ExampleComponent();
    ...
}
```

So I can create an ExampleComponent with:

```
ExampleComponent* test = ExampleComponent::Create();
```

However, I don't like having to friend with the Pool for each subclass that I define, but since friendship is not inherited I can't do it in the parent class.

Is there anyway to omit this with preserving protected constructors? Or is there a better architecture that I could use?